# Setting default focus in mvc form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, focus

I have a page that has multiple tabs on it. Each tab is loaded using a partial view. I want to have the default focus go to the first "textbox" on each of these pages. Here is the problem I'm running into. I add this simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("input[type=text]").first().focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I added this code to the layout master page thinking it would just default to the first text box on each page. That's not the case however. It will default to the first field on the first tab that loads, but when I navigate to a new tab, there is no focus, and when I navigate back to the first tab, still no focus. I have also added this simple code to each one of the partials, no luck there on setting the focus. I've also tried removing the "document.ready" part, no luck there. I've tried adding this to each individual page, in both ways described, no luck. Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: The code you posted is processing as 'on document ready, on document ready, focus first text input'. You only need one of the ready methods:  `$(document).ready(function () { $('input[type=text]').first().focus(); });`

Comment: That still doesn't solve the issue of navigating between tabs. With your code or mine, it focuses the first text box on tab 1, but when i click on tab 2, it loses focus, and never regains it. the tabs are loaded using partial views, as stated, i've even tried adding the code to the partials as well, with no luck.

Comment: Are the tabs actually new pages, or is the switching handled client-side on the same page? I guess a better way to ask... When you go to a new tab, does the url change?

Comment: If you want to focus first text box on each tab, you need to handle tab switch event also to set it

Comment: Url does NOT change. The tab switching is handled client side, as in, there is no call to a method to load those tabs.

Comment: @Skrubb `$(document).ready(...)` only fires when the page loads. When you switch to a new tab, it doesn't fire. If you are using a plugin for your tabs, there is probably an event that fires when the current tab changes. You can use that to select the first input in the tab.

Answer (score 1):

the code you posted will run one time only and will choose the first input (with text type) he will encounter.
you need to:

1)set a parent div for each tab content
 for example :

```
<div id='tab1Content'>
//you'r tab Content
</div>
```

2)bind a trigger for the tab switch, and in that delegate you will need to determine which tab has the focus, than use you'r original code in that way:

```
$('#tab1Content').find("input[type=text]").first().focus();
```

the id ('#tab1Content') will change acording to the focused tab.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after reading the jQuery API documentation for tabs. I've come to the solution of using the "activate" event. So the code would look similar to this:

```
 $( ".selector" ).tabs({
activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

And then the binding would look something like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Thanks for the help though guys!